Why doesn't Typescript infer a union type with a conditional function call?
In this simple case with primitives, Typescript infers the types as a union as I'd expect:
function getIt(numOrStr: boolean) {
  return numOrStr ? 1 : "1";
}

getIt(true) // 1 | "1"

However, if I have a conditional with function calls, then I get unexpected types that prefer the first function call.
function foo() {
    return { a: 1}
}

function bar() {
    return { a: 1, b: 2 }
}

function getIt(fooOrBar: boolean) {
    const getter = fooOrBar ? foo : bar;
    return getter();
}

function getItExplicitType(foorOrBar: boolean): ReturnType<typeof foo> | ReturnType<typeof bar> {
    return foorOrBar ? foo() : bar();
}

function getItCondtionalType<T extends boolean>(fooOrBar: T) {
    const getter = fooOrBar ? foo : bar;
    return getter() as T extends true ? ReturnType<typeof foo> : ReturnType<typeof bar>;
}

getIt(true) // {a: number}
getIt(false) // {a: number}
getItExplicitType(true) // {a: number } | {a: number, b: number}
getItConditionalType(true) // {a: number}
getItConditionalType(false) // {a: number, b: number}

Why does this happen?
sandbox
It works as expected if I specify the types, and even better if I use conditional types. However, I'd prefer to use inferred types for my use case to avoid boilerplate in my ORM.
What's the best way to leverage inferred types?

It's subtype reduction; {a: number, b: number} is a proper subtype of {a: number} (every value of the former type is a valid value of the latter type) and TS sometimes reduces unions in that case. (if every X is a Y then X | Y and Y is the same type.) Sometimes people don't like subtype reduction so you can either manually specify types to keep the union, or you can try to make the types disjoint and not subtypes (e.g., {a: number, b?: never} as shown here). See the linked q/a and the github issues linked within.

And it's worth being clear about this part: "However, if I have a conditional with function calls". This has nothing to do with function calls. What you changed between the first case and the second was that the first case returns types with no overlap, and second case returns types that do overlap.
